# VBA - How to take a single column as input array then output the array removing all odd numbers

Tags: arrays, vba, function

I have a very basic question, but would love to know how to do this. I want to write a function in VBA where I can highlight a column as an input, and then spit out the result somewhere else.

Thanks in advance :)

e.g.  column A
      --------
        10
        8
        5
        6
        1
        3
        2

becomes:

```
 column A
  --------
    10
    8
    6
    2
```

Comment: Will the odd numbers be every other cell, or random cells?

Comment: You could step through each element and check - `<even number> MOD 2` will always return 0, `<odd number> MOD 2` will always return 1.

Comment: The output array has no odd numbers. I would like the output column of even numbers to be in the same order as previously, just without the odd number or any blank cells

Comment: Thanks Darren, I am aware. Just don't know how to work with arrays in functions

Comment: or you could use excels `iseven` function

Comment: I know about iseven and mod. My question is how I could write a function to do this (the function would be able to take a column-array as an input and return an array without even numbers or blanks)

Comment: You need to select an answer, or explain why the answers are not correct, don't leave threads unanswered.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have responded to the response that best answered by question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick.
You can enter as an array-formula directly to a sheet: `{=RemoveOdds(A1:A7)}` or as part of another procedure:

```
Sub Test()
    RemoveOdds Selection
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function RemoveOdds(Target As Range) As Variant

    Dim vFinal() As Variant
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim x As Long

    ReDim vFinal(1 To Target.Cells.Count)

    x = 1
    For Each rCell In Target
        If rCell Mod 2 = 0 Then
            vFinal(x) = rCell.Value
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next rCell

    'So missing values do not show up as 0 at bottom of array.
'    Do While x <= Target.Cells.Count
'        vFinal(x) = ""
'        x = x + 1
'    Loop

    ReDim Preserve vFinal(1 To x - 1)

    'RemoveOdds = vFinal 'Basic array - will place values horizontally on sheet.
    RemoveOdds = Application.Transpose(vFinal) 'Will place values vertically on sheet.

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Darren, will try today

Comment: Hi Darren, apologies for the late reply. This was a function as I had asked and it worked perfectly as I had intended. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I just did it from column a to b, but you probably want range as the current selection and a different output column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub filterlist()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("a1:a5")
Dim celluse As Range
Dim arr As Variant

For Each celluse In rng
    If celluse.Value Mod 2 = 0 Then
        If IsEmpty(arr) Then
            arr = Array(celluse.Value)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
            arr(UBound(arr)) = celluse.Value
        End If
    End If
Next celluse


Dim i As Long    
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)    
    Range("b" & i + 1) = arr(i)
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try this today